# Valores posibles para cada conjunto de variables Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables

Uso Python 2.7

Tengo 5 variables:
`Fillrate, eCPM, Revenue, Impresiones y Oportunidades`.

Cada una puede tomar los valores:

```
ALERTA, Down, Estable, Up, Incremento
```

Necesito saber Cuales opciones puede haber por cada conjunto de variables. Me refiero a algo así:

`["Estable","Estable","Estable","Estable","Estable"],
["Incremento","Estable","Estable","Estable","Estable"],
["Estable","Estable","Estable","Up","Estable"]`

y asi sucesivamente hasta que complete las 3125 posibilidades (5^5)

Comment: Mírate [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Comment: Gracias crack! @FJSevilla

Answer (score 0):

Si bien la respuesta ya la tienes, vamos a pasarla en limpio:

```
from itertools import product

estados = ["Fillrate", "eCPM", "Revenue", "Impresiones", "Oportunidades"]
combinaciones = list(product(estados, repeat=len(estados)))

print(len(combinaciones))
print(combinaciones[345])
> 3125
> ('Fillrate', 'Revenue', 'Impresiones', 'Oportunidades', 'Fillrate')
```

Usamos [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) para generar las combinaciones de los elementos de `estados` pudiendo en este caso repetirse los 5 elementos de la lista `repeat=len(estados)`. Al ser `product()`una función generadora, si queremos una lista deberemos convertirla a tal mediante `list()`, ten en cuenta que los elementos de la lista son tuplas, si necesitaras otra lista podrías hacer:

```
combinaciones = [list(e) for e in product(estados, repeat=len(estados))]
```